# Infer a type from a string in Haskell

Tags: json, haskell, functional-programming, type-inference, aeson

I'm working on a JSON data encoder in Haskell! (to be more specific, I am trying to port [Jo](https://github.com/jpmens/jo) into Haskell!).  I've gotten a lot of it working, but I'm running into a little wrinkle.  I'll try to be concise with my question here, I've tried to strip away as much unneeded context as possible.

Goal: Construct a `Value` given a `String`.

These strings come from the command line:  Users enter in key/value pairs in the form `<key>=<value>`.  After splitting them apart I am left in a `String` that is the value data of unknown type.

Example cases:

```
let s = "someString" -- use the `String` constructor
let s = "1234"       -- use the `Number` constructor
let s = "True"       -- use the `Bool` constructor
```

**Question: How might I infer that the contents of `s` is a `String` vs a `Number`, `Bool`, etc?**

This is the relevant type + constructors for the Aeson `Value` type (edited for brevity).

```
data Value = Object Object
           | Array Array
           | String Text
           | Number Scientific
           | Bool Bool
           | Null
```

Comment: You need (to buy, beg, steal, borrow, or write) a *parser*.

Comment: Did you mean `"\"someString\""`?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. that's what I feared / expected, just not really sure where to get started.  Would you do it with vanilla Haskell? A specific package?  I'm _very_ new to the language and ecosystem, just need to get pointed in the right direction :-)

Comment: @Bergi No I don't believe so.  cases will not contain any quotes as part of the string itself

Comment: @jbakerj Then how do you know it's supposed to be a string and not a `Null` or `Bool` value?

Comment: There is a zillion way to write a parser in Haskell, you need to know at least one. You can start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20660782/writing-a-parser-from-scratch-in-haskell).

Comment: A json string actually [must be quoted](https://www.json.org/json-en.html),.

Comment: Ah, I can clarify.  The values I would like to infer at not yet encoded in JSON.  After I construct a `Value` I pass that into the `Aeson` package for JSON encoding, `Aeson` handles quotes/no quotes, pretty printing with curly braces, etc.  This parsing issue is a little upstream of that: these strings I want to parse are collected from the command line and I need to figure out which `Value` constructor to use so `Aeson` encode them properly.  At no point am I reading JSON.  I will update my question to make that more clear.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction though!

Comment: So you have a *language* (not json, some other language) you are trying to parse (and feed the parsed data to a json encoder, but this is not really relevant). This makes things somewhat clearer. Now an interesting question is how you define a string in that language.

Comment: You need to define (at least on paper) a *grammar* that defines rules like "the string `True` maps to the Boolean value `True`, not the `String` value `"True"`. A parser is just a function that *implements* the rules defined in the grammar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're already using the *aeson* package, you could use [decode](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson/docs/Data-Aeson.html#v:decode). This works because `Value` is also a `ByteString` instance:

```
Prelude Data.Aeson> decode "\"someString\"" :: Maybe Value
Just (String "someString")
Prelude Data.Aeson> decode "1234" :: Maybe Value
Just (Number 1234.0)
Prelude Data.Aeson> decode "true" :: Maybe Value
Just (Bool True)
```

Notice (as *n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m.* points out in the comments) that strings must be quoted.

What you could do, then, is to take your unknown value and first surround it with quotes and attempt to parse it. Then try to parse it again without surrounding quotes.

You now have two `Maybe Value` values. Pick the first `Just` value (and be prepared to deal with the `Nothing` case).

Comment: You want to do those things in the opposite order, surely? If you first try parsing it as a string, you will always succeed. Instead, first try parsing it as something else, and fall back to a string if that fails.

Comment: @amalloy That sounds right. It's one of many reasons that I prefer writing automated tests - I don't trust my own reasoning abilities.

Comment: This was a great suggestion.  Oddly the only type that it 'broke' was string, which will return `Nothing`.  In that case I just passed the string into the `toJSON` value encoder which can already handle strings and things seem to be working well. 
```
toValue :: BL.ByteString -> Value
toValue x = case decode x of
              Just x -> x
              Nothing -> toJSON $ lazyToText x
```